# prove $\int_{0}^{1}h(x)g(x)dx\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx \leq \int_0^{1}g(x)dx\int_{0}^{1}h(x)f(x)dx$

Tags: real-analysis

The $f$ is a convex function. The $g$ is a concave function defined by $f,g : [0,1] \to  [0,\infty)$. And $\lim\limits_{x\to0+} f(x)= \lim\limits_{x\to0+} g(x) =0$. Suppose $h : [0,1] \to \mathbb{R}$ is a strictly increasing function

Prove the $\int_{0}^{1}h(x)g(x)dx\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx \leq \int_0^{1}g(x)dx\int_{0}^{1}h(x)f(x)dx$

In the solution, it proved $f,g$ and $h$ are Riemann integrable on the $[0,1]$.

And next it said, Enough to show $\int_{0}^{1} h(x) \frac{g(x)}{\int_{0}^{1}g(s)ds} dx \leq 
\int_{0}^{1} h(x) \frac{f(x)}{\int_{0}^{1}f(s)ds} dx$

But All of a sudden, it said "without loss generality $\int_{0}^{1} g(s)ds = \int_{0}^{1} f(s)ds =1$"

I can't understand why he supposing like that. Because there aren't enough evidences that $\int_{0}^{1} g(s)ds = \int_{0}^{1} f(s)ds$. Why can we say $\int_{0}^{1} g(s)ds = \int_{0}^{1} f(s)ds$ ?

Comment: Let $f_1 = f/\int f$ and $g_1 = g/\int g$. We have to show $\int h g_1 \le \int h f_1$. But $\int f_1 = \int g_1 = 1$. So it suffices to prove it when the integrals are 1.

Comment: Because of concavity/convexity, the functions are bounded hence integrable on $[0,1]$. If one of them is null almost everywhere, boths sides of the inequality are null. Otherwise, the integrals of $f,g$ are strictly positive, you may divide $f$ and $g$ by their integral and by linearity, it suffices to prove the inequality for the two functions thus normalized.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan. Hmm.. How the linearity applied in my post? As far as I've known the linearity is $\int a f + bg  = a\int f + b\int g$. But I can't find this method applied.

Comment: Riemann integral is a linear form on the space of all integrable functions on [0,1]. If you divide $f$ by some non null quantity, you divide $fh$ and the integral of $fh$ by the same quantity.

Comment: @Gribouillis. How can I deduce $\int_{0}^{1} g(s)ds = \int_{0}^{1} f(s)ds$ from the  $\int f_1 dx = \int g_1 dx=1$ you've suggested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meaning of the «without loss of generality» is that if we are able to prove the result for *all* $f$ and $g$ satisfying the hypotheses plus the supplementary hypotheses that $\int_0^1 f(x)dx=\int_0^1 g(x)dx=1$,
then we are able to prove the result for every $f$ and $g$.

The reason is that for general (non zero) $f$ and $g$, the functions $f_1 = \frac{f}{\int_0^1 f(s)ds}$ and $g_1 = \frac{g}{\int_0^1 g(s)ds}$ satisfy the hypotheses plus the additional hypotheses and that proving the result for $f$ and $g$ is equivalent to proving the result for $f_1$ and $g_1$.